# Undefined index: GET request

Tags: php, get

In my website files, I have 3 files, a file that has some basic **PHP** code such as collecting user data, and to make the code organized, I include the **templates** and the **form** files instead of writing their code in the same page.

So, I have the form included after the templates file. Now, after submitting the form, I wanna show the error code (if exists) but I cannot send it to the first page (that is included before it) because it will say `Undefined variable`. and I tried sending the variable using `$_SESSION` but it wasn't a good idea because even after refreshing the page, the error will stay.

So, I decided to make it with `GET` requests. (ex: http://website.com/form?status=failed&error=gender).

And the code that gets the `GET` value is:

```
$status = $_GET['status'];
$error = $_GET['error'];

$error1 = "You have to choose the gender.";

if ($status == "failed"){
    if ($error == "gender"){
        $message = $error1;
        echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<h4 class="tab-info">Complete these steps in order to get posts related to your interests.</h4>';
}
```

In case that `$status` or `$error` were empty (http://website.com/form) **not submitted yet**, it will give the following error: `Undefined index: status in **path**`, how can this be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to code for the first time a page loads and the `$_GET` or `$_POST` values have not been set because the form has not been submitted or the page has been run without the required querystring.

So always check that the parameters exists before using them

```
$status = isset($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : '';
$error = isset($_GET['error'] ? $_GET['error'] : '';
```

This will make sure you dont attempt to use `$_GET['status']` usless it actually exists and  that your 2 variables a) exist and b) have some value even if it is a default like `''` in this case

Comment: what does `?` and `:` mean in that code?

Comment: It works like an IF statement If isset do code after the `?` else do code after the `:`